# Can we have Stack-Overflow chat-rooms application for iOS and Android?

Tags: feature-request, chat

Since Stack Overflow is becoming popular and favorite for Enthusiastic Programmers and chat rooms on Stack Overflow are really very helpful to discuss technical stuffs.

If we have chat application developed for iOS and Android it will be a good step towards making the community better. Since many of the members would like to stay online while they are travelling or away from their computers will be able to communicate if chat application is available for mobiles.

This is just a suggestion of mine to make our Community more fruitful.

Comment: There is an [unofficial Android app](http://stackapps.com/q/585/5930) that claims to have chat support. I don't know how well it works though.

Comment: It basically just wraps the browser, nothing special AFAIR @nhinkle

Comment: What about Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score -2):

You can access the chat rooms from iOS & Android browser. The chat system doesn't have an official API - so any chat application would end up embedding a web browser view into the app, which makes no sense.

Comment: If it were an official app, it would't be limited to official APIs.

Comment: @JeremyBanksʬʬʬ yeah, valid point.

Comment: @Sathya: We can always access it through browser but if there is an application it would be a lot easier. You always have option to chat on facebook or Yahoo from browser but if you have application than obviously you would prefer that. :-)